# Comparing multiple rows in two large tables

Tags: mysql

I have two large tables with over 10mil records in each. I'm trying to find out which values one of the tables is missing. The table have the identical schema and look like this

Table1

```
| ColA       | ColB        | ColC         |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| John       | Steve       | Richardson   |
| Steve      | Richard     | Johnson      |
| Will       | Jack        | Jackson      |
```

Table2

```
| ColA       | ColB        | ColC         |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| John       | Steve       | Richardson   |
| Will       | Jack        | Jackson      |
```

I'm looking for the *Steve Richard Johnson* record

I tried the following query, but it times out

```
SELECT *
FROM `Table1` AS a
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM `Table2` AS b WHERE 
`a`.`ColA` = `b`.`ColA` AND `a`.`ColB` = `b`.`ColB` AND `a`.`ColC` = `b`.`ColC`)
```

Comment: Are you interested in which rows are missing from table2 only, or also which rows are present in table 2 but missing from table 1

Comment: @Strawberry I'm only interested in the rows that are missing from table2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply left join with table2 from t1 to get the non matching row as below

```
select t1.* 
from table1 t1 
left join Table2 t2 on t1.col1A = t2.colA and t1.colB = t2.colB and t1.colC = t2.colC
where t2.colA is null and t2.cOlB is null and t2.colC is null
```

Comment: You only need to test for one of the columns in t2 being null

Comment: The query times out before it finishes even though have indexes on ColA, ColB and ColC